# 'playing in films' or 'acting in films', which is correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

For example, in this sentence:

> Jodie Foster started __ in films when she was very young.

Looks like both are correct but it should be one.

Comment: Why do you think both cannot be correct?

Comment: Because ["acting in films" is so much more common than "playing in films"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acting+in+films%2Cplaying+in+films%2Cact+in+films%2Cplay+in+films%2Cacted+in+films%2Cplayed+in+films&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) I think you would have to have a very specific reason to use *playing*.

Comment: I have the same question as @DavidSiegel. Is this a homework assignment? Please [cite the source of the text](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "*playing*" and "*acting*" may be used for what an actor dfoes in a play, film, video or TV show. Indeed "*player*" is another term for "*actor*", and it normally has much the same meaning,

The word "acting" is generally used more frequently than "playing" for the general concept. "Playing" is more often used when indicating specific parts played by a given actor, as in:

> - The role of Ophelia was played by Joan Sutherland.
> - Fred Searls, playing Tom Sawyer, does a first rate job ...

But either term may be used, the choice is a matter of style.